# Sight adjustments on the Gamo Compact air pistol

Tags: equipment, shooting

I shoot 10 meter air pistol with the Gamo Compact. When adjusting the sights, how much does one click left/right and up/down, respectively, correspond to on the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One click is half a ring in any direction.

Each pistol or rifle has its own click system as is mentioned in their respective manuals. However, this rule of thumb comes from practical experience of shooting and rotating clicks accordingly.

Comment: This correctness of this answer seems reasonable. Do you have a reference to support it?

Comment: no as each rifle pistol has its own click system and is mentioned in their respective manuals there might be some docs available if search engines are skimmed but there is no ref doc as it comes by practical experience of shooting and rotating clicks accordingly

Comment: I'm loathe to remove this answer, as it seems correct. I'm going to try to edit the comment into the question in the hope that improves it.

Comment: cool no probs you did a good editorial work sturdo